# Excel VBA suddenly not able to open workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is very strange.

I was programming a macro to open workbooks and extract data which was going fine when it hung one time. I had to end process in task manager and restarted excel.

Now even basic file opening code doesn't work.

My basic code is like this

```
File path is C:/ and fileName is Book1
Set wbOpen (filePath & fileName)
        wbopen.activeSheet.Range ("A1") = "Test" 
        .close SaveChanges:= True
        Msgbox "ok" 

.... end sub
```

The code used to work and i would see book1 being opened on the taskbar and the cell A1 will be changed. Now i still get the Ok message but the cells arent changed and i dont see book1 being opened. Any idea? Pls and thank you

Tried it on another PC and it doesnt work, could be excel settings

Already reset settings using the /regserver method  and deleted the .vbe files under AppData too.

Comment: Sry for bad formatting, typing on phone

Comment: I tries Workbooks.Open ("C:\Excel\Book1.xlsx") in the immediate window and it works. It works in the macro as well but the loop is still not functioning even if if the dir is *.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, was a very stupid mistake, must have accidentally set file path to "C:/Excel" instead of "C:/Excel/"

Tracked it down by using the msg box to print out the file im trying to access